# Rendering html code in view which is generated in controller of asp.nt mvc

Tags: menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I am implementing a role based menu. I have to generate the menu from the database dynamically. I have a role-feature mapping table from where I can get the features that are mapped to the role. Once I get that I have to generate the HTML menus `with <ul> and <li>`. Can I get suggestion as to how that be done. I mean generating the HTML script in controller and rendering it on to the respective view. Please help. Any suggestion is welcomed.

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Dashboard", "User")
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>User</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create User", "CreateUser", "User")</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>Report</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("ABC Report", "ABC", "Report")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Report", "UserReport", "Report")</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>XYZ</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("XYZ1", "XYZ1", "XYZ")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("XYZ2", "XYZ2", "XYZ")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("XYZ3", "XYZ3", "XYZ")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("XYZ4", "XYZ4", "XYZ")</li>
    </ul>
  </li>                      
</ul>
```

Above HTML I have to build in controller and render to the view.

Comment: Why do you need to build it in controller?

Comment: @RezaRahmati : coz it is dynamic.

Comment: Can you pass a list of menus (consist of text and link) to your view from controller?

Comment: @user2998990, You need to explain what the data is that determines what you tryng to display, for example are your storing the link text, controller name and action name related to each role?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a `Menu` class as below

```
public class Menu
{
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public string Controller {get;set;}
   public string Action {get;set;}
}
```

then in your `viewModel` add a property `MenuList` of type `List<Menu>` then fill that collection in your controller dynamically from your database

then change your view as below

```
<a href="#"><span>XYZ</span></a>
<ul>
  @for(var menu in Model.MenuList)
  {
     <li>@Html.ActionLink(menu.Text, menu.Action, menu.Controller)</li>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Probably would be best to have this as a separate child action and rendered in the main view (or layout) with `@Html.Action()` Then the model would just be `IEnumerable<Menu>`