# how to render actionlink to view form controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

```
 ViewBag.htmml = "<li>" + "Html.ActionLink(" + "Home" + ", " + "Dashboard" + ", " + "User" + ")" + "</li>";
```

Above is my code, using which I am trying render an `ActioLink` to my view. When the code runs, using the following code, I don't get an actionlink with name as Home, instead i get `Html.ActionLink(Home, Dashboard, User)` in my `<li>` part. How to get an ActionLink with what I am trying.

```
 @Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmml)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the controller and not in the view (razor code is parsed in the view)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : hi stephen again, please refer to this link of mine. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186208/rendering-html-code-in-view-which-is-generated-in-controller-of-asp-nt-mvc. I am trying to build a menu from database.

Comment: I don't understand the other question either :). Your razor code needs to be in the view. What is in the database that determines what you want to render?

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Muecke have mentioned, HTML needs to be generated in the View, not in the Controller.

However, if you insist on creating it in the Controller, you need to have an `HtmlHelper` available for you to call the `ActionLink` method. But, as the name suggests, `HtmlHelper` is only available automatically for you in the View.

You *can* create one yourself manually (using a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621261) for example), but this is very inefficient and error-prone.

But, since you're only trying to generate an `<a>` element, and you already are creating the elements yourself (like the `<li>` element), you can simply do this (using the `UrlHelper` that *is* available in the Controller as well):

```
ViewBag.htmml = "<li><a href=\"" +
                 Url.Action("Dashboard", "User") +
                 "\">Home</a></li>";
```