# Fetching data from SQL database to html hover dropdown list in Bootstrap MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

i am working on my **MVCOnlineShop** , this what i made so far:
[image]
i wrote a code before in a `View` so i can link the products to their category and it worked , all categories and products database are in an `SQL server`. this is the code:

```
@model MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}
<h2>Browsing Category: @Model.CategoryName</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var Product in Model.Products)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName,
"Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID })
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

**Question:** Now how can i use this code to show products under their category in a `bootstrap` drop down list? so i want to **click** or **hover** on games for example and i want to get a drop down list that have game 1, game 2, game 3. thanks! and this is what i tried in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

@{
    // stores the Session content in a var
    var Categories = Session["Categories"] as List<Category>;
}

@*Checks if the Session variable is correct*@
@if (Categories != null)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @*For each category in the Session var, display the link*@

            @foreach (var Category in Categories)
            {
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">@Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName, "Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

            }

</ul>
}
```

and this is the category class from `SQL`, `Category.cs`:

```
namespace MVCOnlineShop.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps you out bro :)  -->
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087175/mvc-dynamic-menu-populating-plain-text/43141577#43141577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a `CategoryLayout.cshtml` `Partial View` , and it worked , now i can see categories with products under them all data from `SQL`, this is the code :

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CategoryLayout";
}

@foreach (var Category in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">
                @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName,
"ProductList", new { Category = Category.CategoryID }, new { @style = "color:#1ABC9C;text-decoration:none;" })
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-content">
            @foreach (var Product in Category.Products)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName,
     "Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID }, new { style = "text-decoration:none;" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your foreach loop should be :**

```
@foreach(var category in Categories)
   {
      @Html.LabelFor(category.CategoryName)
      @foreach(var product in category.Products)
      {
         <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
             <button class="dropbtn">@Html.ActionLink(product.ProductName, "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = Product.CategoryID, title = Product.ProductName }, null)</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      }
   }
```

Comment: You have values in Categories?

Comment: Add your Category model

Comment: I am asking have check with breakpoints on view @foreach (var Category in Categories) and you getting values or not

Comment: getting this error :
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@".